# Ceedling No such file or directory issue, how to solve?

Tags: c, ceedling

I am trying to set up ceedling for a C project, however, I keep getting this No such file or directory even though I have linked where the files are to the paths.

For example:

errors:

```
Linking test_omsec_api.txt...
../../source/dialog_sdk/sdk/app_modules/src/app_common/app_task.c:26:56: fatal error: rwip_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "rwip_config.h"            // SW configuration
                                                        ^
compilation terminated.
../../source/dialog_sdk/sdk/app_modules/src/app_common/app_utils.c:46:23: fatal error: app_utils.h: No such file or directory
 #include "app_utils.h"
```

The paths:

```
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - ../../source/**
  :support:
    - test/support
  :libraries: # []
    - ../../source/dialog_sdk/sdk/**
    - ../../source/dialog_sdk/sdk/ble_stack/**
    - ../../source/dialog_sdk/sdk/app_modules/src/app_common/**
    - ../../source/dialog_sdk/sdk/platform/core_modules/rwip/api/**
```

rwip_config.h is inside .../rwip/api/ directory. So I am out of idea how to fix this errors to compile ceedling.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your compilation commands. Did you add the path to the include folder or to the library folder option for your compiler?

Comment: Is 'app_utils.h' in the app_common directory, with 'app_task.c' and 'app_utils.c'? Although the include statements are for local files, it sounds like the MAKEFILE for the project should specify an INCLUDE path that includes `platform/core_modules/rwip/api`.